# how can use random numbers in array?

Tags: java, arrays

I write code by java but I need convert it to hard copy (that means no enter element by user). I need the program work automatically by using random number. I know the method for random.
This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

class arr
    {

        public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
            {
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                int ar[]=new int[100];
                int n,i,j,pos,ch;
                System.out.print("Enter number of element :-");
                n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                if(n<=99)
                    {
                        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                            {
                                System.out.print("Enter any no :-");
                                ar[i]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                            }
                        do
                            {
                                System.out.println("\n1.Ele insert...");
                                System.out.println("2.Ele delete...");
                                System.out.println("3.Ele display...");
                                System.out.println("4.Exit");
                                System.out.print("Enter your choice :-");
                                ch=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                                switch(ch)
                                    {
                                        case 1:
                                            System.out.print("Enter position number :-");
                                            pos=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                                            if(pos<n)
                                                {
                                                    for(j=n-1;j>=pos-1;j--)
                                                        ar[j+1]=ar[j];
                                                    System.out.print("Enter new inserting element :-");
                                                    ar[j+1]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                                                    n++;
                                                }
                                            else
                                                System.out.println("Sory invalid position number enterde.....");
                                            break;
                                        case 2:
                                            System.out.print("Enter position number :-");
                                            pos=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                                            if(pos<n)
                                                {
                                                    for(j=pos-1;j<n;j++)
                                                        ar[j]=ar[j+1];
                                                    System.out.println("element deleted......");
                                                    n--;
                                                }
                                            else
                                                System.out.println("Sory invalid position number enterde.....");
                                            break;
                                        case 3:
                                            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                                                System.out.print(ar[i]+"\t");
                                            System.out.println();
                                            break;
                                        case 4:
                                            System.out.println("Program end.......");
                                            break;
                                        default:
                                            System.out.println("Invalid enter select......");
                                    }
                            }while(ch != 4 );
                    }
                else
                    System.out.println("Out of range........");

            }
    }
```

so my questions are:

- how can use random number
- and I want to add more function for find the smallest number and largest number

I have tried using this method for random:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class ArrayRandom{
    public static void main(String args[]){ 
        Random r = new Random();
        int arr[] = new int[20];
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            //random numbers from 1 to 10:
            arr[i] = r.nextInt(10) + 1;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){    
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not work?

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, it's unreadable. Edit your question to add it next time. Your question is very unclear, and your 'ArrayRandom' class _does_ work, so please edit your question to explain better what is not working, or missing, in your code.

Comment: Its working. What do you expect it from?

Comment: the code work but the numbers inter by user

Comment: @user578613:) What do you mean "numbers inter by user"? Sounds like an alien language. I don't get.

Comment: Clear your question properly to us. Otherwise you won't get the answer.

Comment: sorry (the user who is enter the number) but i wanna the code use random number

Comment: the random number is easy to calculate the time efficiency?

Comment: The code that uses random numbers has already been posted by you yourself in the second code snippet. What else you want here?

Comment: when i add the random to the basic code the outis not look like what i wanna ?

Comment: OK, post the expected output, actual output and any errors you get. Just saying that it does not work, well, does not work here :-)

Comment: how can show you the code ???

Comment: Do you want the program to run without any user input? Do you want random numbers to replace this input?

Answer (score 0):

So I actually parsed-out the code from your comment (kudos to @Mat for the edit, BTW) and dropped it into Eclipse.  And it wrote-out 20 random numbers from 1-10 just fine.  You'll have to be a little more specific on what you mean by "does not work."

As far as getting the lowest and highest, you could try something like this for the lowest:

```
private int findLowest(int[] numberList)
{
    //set the first item in the array as the lowest
    int intLowest = numberList[0];

    //then check if any of the remaining numbers are lower
    for (int intCounter = 1; intCounter < numberList.length; intCounter++)
    {
        if (numberList[intCounter] < intLowest)
        {
            intLowest = numberList[intCounter];
        }
    }
    return intLowest;
}
```

Of course, you'll need to declare this function as "static" if you add it to your ArrayRandom class.  Based-on this, it shouldn't be too difficult to come up with something to find the highest number.

Comment: Which class?  Arr or ArrayRandom?

Comment: And this is where I'm going to say that I think you've been given (more than) enough information to try and piece this together on your own.

Answer (score 0):

This class will produce an randomly filled Array or random size. Is it that what you want?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ArrRandom {
    public static void main (String args[]) { 
        Random r = new Random();
        int arr[] = new int[r.nextInt (100)];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            //random numbers from 1 to 10:
            arr[i] = r.nextInt(10) + 1;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){    
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```